# How to add values legend to a line chart?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'am using JasperReport and ireport 4.0,

I want to add to my charts values like the following:

**This is what I have now:**

[image]

This is what I want to have:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

there is no 'Show Labels' attribute for the line plot. But you can render the labels visible using a chart customizer:

```
public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart){
LineAndShapeRenderer lineRenderer = (LineAndShapeRenderer)chart.getCategoryPlot().getRenderer();
lineRenderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator());
lineRenderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
}
```

If it's an XY line chart, use an XYPlot and a StandardXYItemLabelGenerator in the above code snippet.